# Why do some transactions use more gas than others, even when they send the same ERC20 token?

Tags: erc-20, gas

Why do some transactions use more gas than others, even when they are transferring the same ERC20 token, for example USDC. Even when the receiver is the same and the transferred amount is the same.
This one used 42,381 gas:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x05c86098176a2d7d7d85375c7745503c36b7abc7dbdcbcdd01802859b6fec3a9
This one used 27,381 gas:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4499361f0ab60aed804f6d4ead7aa2ec0f801dcc3cfa1d945bd82c1081ca8611

Answer (score 2):

The difference of 15,000 gas is caused by a gas refund which occurs when storage is cleared (see [Yellow Paper Appendix G](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)):

> Rsclear 15000 Refund given (added into refund counter) when the storage value is set to zero from non-zero.

Comment: To clarify: the gas consumption depends on if the receiver has already tokens and if the sender has zero tokens after the transaction is done.

Comment: So this refund happenes automatically, if I send all my token, because there is nothing to be recorded in the blockchain anymore. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.